# How can I show a tooltip on part of an element's background?

Tags: html, css

I have a div with text that wraps image from every side. I want to add tooltip text when user's pointer hovers this image but I do not know how as this is very specific case and there is no separate img tag for this image. To see what's going on just take a look at [my codepen](https://codepen.io/Kiubaz/pen/VwKdGOe?editors=1100). My essential code:

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}

div.box {
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
  font-size: 0;
  width: 50%;
  --R: 150px;
  /* radius */
  --m: 5px;
  /* margin */
  --t: 50px;
  /* distance from top */
}

p {
  font-size: 20px;
}

div.box p {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 var(--m);
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: justify;
}

div.box p:before {
  content: "";
  width: var(--R);
  height: calc(2*var(--R));
  padding: var(--m) 0 var(--m) var(--m);
  margin-top: var(--t);
  background: var(--img);
  background-size: 200% 100%;
  shape-outside: circle(var(--R) at var(--d, right) calc(-1*var(--m)) top calc(50% + var(--t)/2));
  float: right;
  border-radius: 500px 0 0 500px;
  margin-right: calc(-1*var(--m));
}

div.box p:last-child:before {
  float: left;
  padding: var(--m) var(--m) var(--m) 0;
  --d: left;
  background-position: right;
  border-radius: 0 500px 500px 0;
  margin-left: calc(-1*var(--m));
  margin-right: 0;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.box {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}

.box p .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  /* Position the tooltip */
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

.box p:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="box" style="--img:url(https://jakuwegiel.web.app/assets/images/DSC_0925a-1.png)">
  <p>
    <span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip text</span> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and
    scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem
    Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
    survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing
    software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </p>
</div>
```

Is there anything you need more? Maybe should I be more precise?

Comment: So you want to target hover on a background image?

Comment: Yes this is what I want

Comment: That won't be possible. You might put an absolutely-positioned invisible element behind the content on which to put the title.

Comment: Ok, could you tell me how to do that?